# Переход на новую страницу

Tags: java, android

Я создал шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity в Android Studio. В нем есть несколько фрагментов. В одном из них я расположил кнопку. При нажатии на нее пользователь должен перейти на новую страницу (или fragment, или activity). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это осуществить.
Пробовал так:

```
public void OnBtnClick(){
    this.btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("ru.example.blippy.Activity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Не работает

Comment: Так Вам надо переход на фрагмент или активити ? И просто переход или переход между фрагментами в шторке ?

Comment: @MakoStorm , у меня есть несколько фрагментов. Один из них главный. В выплывающем (боковом) меню переходы между ними настроены. В главном фрагменте есть кнопка, например, "Начать", при нажатии на которую нужно открыть новое окно. Это новое окно будет представлять из себя или фрагмент, или активити (посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что лучше), в котором я реализую, например, алгоритм по переводу чисел из десятичной системы в двоичную.

Comment: Шторка работает с фрагментами, если Вам надо встроить эту систему в одну из вкладок на шторке - значит используйте фрагмент. Если Вы хотите, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалась новая активити, значит используйте `Intent`.

Comment: @MakoStorm , cпасибо, пробовал с `Intent`, писал в MainActivity, но не работает. Не понимаю почему. Его же не надо было прописывать в классе FragmentHome (Home - название фрагмента)?

Comment: У Вас должны быть фрагменты и одна Активити, на которой все стоит. При смене вкладок фрагменты просто замещают друг-друга. Если Вы создаете переход на другую Активити, должно все работать. Его не надо прописывать там. Просто реализуйте всю работу с фрагментами и все.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru). Объявите его указав вторую активити. Например, `Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourContext,SecondActivity.class)`. Что бы сработало намерение нужно вызвать функцию 
`startActivity(myIntent)`.